# Javascript: Asking how to cancel an alert entirely when i press it many times i should cancel all the calls of the function

Tags: javascript

I have this sample of code that cancel 1 alert at a time:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-`scale=1.0">`
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Click the first button alert "Hello" after 3 second</p>
        <p>Click the second button to cancel the alert</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop the Alert</button>
        <script>
        var myVar;
        function myFunction(){
            myVar=setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);
        }
        function myStopFunction(){
            clearTimeout(myVar);
        }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But i wanted to cancel all the alert if you press on try it for example
like 3 or 4 times it will have 4 or 3 alerts but if you press on the try it
and alert 3 times and 3 times on the button stop my alert the alert will
cancel.
so the number of clicks will be equal. I wanna create a function in which if you press on try it million times
then press 1 time on stop the alert the alert cancel no matter what.
I tried implementing this code and didn't work out so i need help please.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-`scale=1.0">`
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Click the first button alert "Hello" after 3 second</p>
        <p>Click the second button to cancel the alert</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop the Alert</button>
        <script>
        var myVar;
        var c`enter code here`ounter=0;
        function myFunction(){
            myVar=setTimeout(function(){alert("HEllo")},3000);
            counter++;
        }
        function myStopFunction(){
            for(var i =0;i<counter+1;i++){   
                     clearTimeout(myVar);
                     counter--;
                     }
        }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to set loads of timeouts? why not just clear the timeout before resetting it, then you only have one timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your code remove just the last timeoutID.

You can put your timeoutID into an array. After you can clear all your timeoutID into a loop.

```js
var arrTimeout = [];

function myFunction() {
  var myVar = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Hello");
  }, 3000);
  arrTimeout.push(myVar);
}

function myStopFunction() {
  arrTimeout.forEach((timeoutID) => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  })

  arrTimeout = [];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop the Alert</button>
```

### OLD JS version

```js
var arrTimeout = [];

function myFunction() {
  var myVar = setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Hello");
  }, 3000);
  arrTimeout.push(myVar);
}

function myStopFunction() {
  for (var l = arrTimeout.length; l--;) {
    clearTimeout(arrTimeout[l]);
  }
  arrTimeout = [];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop the Alert</button>
```

Comment: bro your code doesn't work, and im asking a specific question which is using the alert command in java script not using the console.log which prints on the page because the alert get executed by the number of clicks you click on the try it. thank you

Comment: I need help please! anyone! ??

Comment: First I am not your bro... And my code work. If you want alert, change console.log by alert. And you are using Javascript not java script

Comment: okay. But i tried your code and replaced by the alert command and still doesn't work. I appreciate your help man, but please try it again using the alert.

Comment: My code work, can you describe the trouble, and the browser used.

Comment: the browser used google chrome. editor visual studio code community edition.

Comment: Explanation: when i press on the try it 4 times and one time on the stop button the alert doesn't stop. it gets executed 3 times instead of 4. i need a code that stops the alert permanently whenever i press on the stop the alert button thank you

Comment: can you help me please ?

Comment: i tried using a for loop to stop the alerts 1 by 1 see my code above but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry man. I didn't understand can you edit your code or implement it. I would appreciate your help, because my doctor will give me minus grades if i don't do it right thank you.

Comment: thanks man. now i can show him the code. it worked. Awesome thank you a lot!

Comment: yeah sure thing @R3tep i saved the answer.

Comment: but how do i close the post ?